# 100% screen height with purely CSS

Tags: css

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I have markup like such:

```
<section id="container">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

How can I get each article to be the full height of the window by using purely CSS, and no JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure that the html, body and #container tags are also at a height of 100%:

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aXPwL/1/

Comment: Well each article is not 100% screen height on my screen on your fiddle anyway.

Comment: It's not 100% of the screen height, but 100% of the window height (as stated in the question). Or am I missing something here? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="container" style="height:100%">
    <article style="height:100%;"></article>
    <article style="height:100%;"></article>
    <article style="height:100%;"></article>
    <article style="height:100%;"></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

All elements starting from html cascading down to the article element need to have 100% height specified, otherwise any child element will always be only as tall as its parent element.

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBJ94/) to show that

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
} 
section {
  height: 100%;
}
article {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also note, not sure if this is what you want, but since the articles are not stacked on top of each other, the user will have to scroll down to see all 4 articles, making the actual page height 4x the height of the browser window.